# ClickEvent fires twice and returns the wrong value for .contains()

Tags: reactjs

I am designing a simple dropdown that should close toggle automatically if the user clicks somewhere on the page that is not the dropdown. I am having a hard time understanding the behaviour, though. This is my component:

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component<IProps> {
    private dropdown = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

    handleClick(e: any) {
        e.stopPropagation() // this doesn't change the result
        if (this.dropdown?.current?.contains(e.target)) {
            console.log(this.dropdown.current.contains(e.target))
            console.log(e.target.className)
            // keep dropdown open
            return;
        }
        // close dropdown
        console.log(e.target.className)
        console.log(this.dropdown?.current?.contains(e.target))
        return;
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this), false)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this), false)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Wrapper ref={this.dropdown} className="wrapper">
                <Comp>
                    <div className="divdiv" style={{height: '5rem', width: '5rem', backgroundColor: 'red'}}></div>
                </Comp>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}
```

This output is quite confusing for me. If I click on the `div` with the `className='divdiv'` **once**. I'm getting:

[image]

I would expect the `onClick eventHandler` to be only executed once. And even if it executes x times due to bubbling I would expect `.contains()` to always return `true` since the `target` remains the same.

Comment: It's normal for an event to _bubble_ up, you should call `e.stopPropagation()` to avoid the event going through each of the DOM elements.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Same result.

Comment: Are you mounting two dropdowns on the same page? If so, that would be expected.

Comment: ah, yeah - you are right. I'm doing that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are having two different instances of the `<Dropdown/>` component on the same page and hence two different `handleClick()` handlers.

Since, both the instances are registering *click* event handlers on the `document` node only, `handleClick()` of both the instances are getting fired on the page click. The expected output of `true` and then `divdiv` is from the `handleClick` of the dropdown which you are interacting with while testing. But, the second **unexpected** output of `divdiv` followed by `false` is from the `handleClick()` of the second dropdown, you are not interacting with, and therefore not expecting an output.

Let's say you have one more instance of your `<Dropdown/>` component, on the same page, you would be getting one more log of `divdiv` followed by `false` in addition to the four logs you are already getting, like so:

```
true    // from the "first" <Dropdown/> instance
divdiv  // from the "first" <Dropdown/> instance
divdiv  // from the "second" <Dropdown/> instance
false   // from the "second" <Dropdown/> instance
divdiv  // from the "third" <Dropdown/> instance
false   // from the "third" <Dropdown/> instance
```